# Is UITabBar's Icon must be monochrome?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbar

It seems that all color except transparency count as one color. If I use this pictures, all I get is a big box and only the first 2 lines are drawn.

What do do if we want colourful tab bar icons then?

[image]

Note: If I use the image above, what I get is this:

[image]

There isn't anyway to make colorful tab bar icons isn't it? Where is this documented anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the image you use for a custom tab bar icon is just used as a mask to create the icon you will see when the app runs. It should be white with appropriate alpha trasparency. This is documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html